# Nginx redirect if url contain "/?&"

Tags: nginx, redirect

I need help redirect if url only contain "/?&"

Example:

```
https://example.com/?&
```

redirect to:

```
https://example.com/
```

already try with this code but not working.

```
location /?& {
  return 301 http://$server_name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `location` and `rewrite` directives operate on a [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which does not include the query string (that part of the URI from the `?` onwards).

To redirect all URIs ending with `?&`, you could test the `$args` variable. For example:

```
if ($args = "&") { return 301 $uri; }
```

Or, to only redirect the URI `/?&`, you could test the `$request_uri` variable. For example:

```
if ($request_uri = "/?&") { return 301 /; }
```